# C# WindowsForms - Radio button comment/uncomment content of textbox keypress, textchanged and focusleave

Tags: c#, textbox, comments, radio-button

i have 3 radio buttons:

```
rbtPercentualmedioanual
rbtPercentualmensal
rbtValorfixo
```

I would like to change options events for textbox1 according choosed option

If chose rbtValorfixo,
It will uncomment:

```
private void textbox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //substituipontovirgula_textBox(sender as TextBox, e);
}

private void textbox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //formatamoeda_textBox(sender as TextBox, e);
}
private void textbox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    //numeropontoouvirgula_textBox(sender as TextBox, e);
    formatarporcentagem_textBox(sender as TextBox, e);
}
```

and will comment

```
private void textbox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        numeropontoouvirgula_textBox(sender as TextBox, e);
        //formatarporcentagem_textBox(sender as TextBox, e);
    }
```

---

If choose option rbtPercentualmedioanual or rbtPercentualmensal, it will comment:

```
private void textbox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    substituipontovirgula_textBox(sender as TextBox, e);
}

private void textbox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    formatamoeda_textBox(sender as TextBox, e);
}
private void textbox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    numeropontoouvirgula_textBox(sender as TextBox, e);
    //formatarporcentagem_textBox(sender as TextBox, e);
}
```

and will uncomment: formatarporcentagem_textBox

```
private void textbox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    //numeropontoouvirgula_textBox(sender as TextBox, e);
    //formatarporcentagem_textBox(sender as TextBox, e);
}
```

i dont know how comment/uncomment keypress, textchanged or focusleave event using radiobutton check, only say how, not need make all, i can do it, but i have to know if its possible and if is, how ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can determine if a radiobutton or checkbox is checked by the radioButton.Checked property.

In you case it will be something like this:

```
private void textbox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!rbtValorfixo.Checked)
      substituipontovirgula_textBox(sender as TextBox, e);
}
```

or:

```
private void textbox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if(rbtValorfixo.Checked)
      numeropontoouvirgula_textBox(sender as TextBox, e);
    else
      formatarporcentagem_textBox(sender as TextBox, e);
}
```

and so on.

Comment: Thanks for that . i dont know what happened, hehe. I was so noob. Should be because i am working for hours and inverted my mind trying change values from radiobutton and not from textbox, rsrs. Anyway thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to comment or uncommment code. Being within a programming language, you need to look out for right structures.

In this rather simple case, you just need an "if" block.

[This might help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/5011f09h%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: i know, its working now, i dont know what happened to me, hehe. I was so noob. Should be because i am working for hours and inverted my mind trying change values from radiobutton and not from textbox, rsrs. Anyway thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use something like this? Not sure as it's quite unclear what you are trying to say.
private void Operation_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RadioButton rbt = sender as RadioButton;
            if (btn != null)

```
            {
                case "rbtPercentualmedioanual":
                    _operation = new example2();
                    example1.Visible = true;
                    example2.Visible = true;
                    example3.Visible = false;

                    return;

                case "rbtPercentualmensal":
                    _operation = new example3();
                    example1.Visible = true;
                    example2.Visible = true;
                    example3.Visible = false;

                    return;

                case "rbtValorfixo":
                    _operation = new example1();
                    example1.Visible = true;
                    example2.Visible = true;
                    example3.Visible = false;


                default:
                    break;
```

And change it to what you want to show